# Sonar/Jacoco measured test coverage degrades by every commit for no obvious reason

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a SpringBoot Maven multi module project with sonar integration configured as follows:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    ...
    <sonar.projectKey>${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectKey>
    <sonar.projectName>${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectName>
    <sonar.sources>src/</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test/</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/test/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
</properties>
...
<plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
        <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <output>file</output>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</dataFile>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/../target/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now I run into the strange phenomenon that the test coverage of this project (according to JaCoCo) degrades over time. Commits changing just one line (which was covered before and is covered after) can result in a 0.1% lower coverage.

This began after a refactoring of the module structure; before each submodule had SpringBoot as parent, while it was recorded as child of the (real) parent module. I changed that so that now each module has the parent module as parent and gets SpringBoot inserted via maven plugin. This works well so far; only after that the count of unit tests sank by five; whereas test from every module are recorded. I could not yet identify which tests are missing as we we have several hundreds of them in this project.

And (as mentioned) with every code change the coverage detected degrades. Before the module refactoring a coverage of nearly 80% was shown; now it has sunken to 26% without much code added or tests removed.

Update:
I have found some warnings in the build log:

> [WARNING] The following class(es) did not match with execution data:

...

> [WARNING] In order to have accurate coverage measures, the same class files must be used as at runtime for report generation.
>
> [INFO] No information about coverage per test.

Given is a list of some few classes, but by far not all. And they are from any submodule.
What have I done wrong?
How could I have used another compiler/build chain or whatever for some classes? These are not instrumented by another agents.